# How to use both ethernet and wifi connection at the same time in windows 8.1

Tags: ethernet, wifi-configuration

I have a windows 8.1 laptop, and it is connected to both wifi and an ethernet cable. But only one can be used at a time, but some apps only work on wifi and some only works on ethernet. Is there a way I can have both connected, and then per software connection, it tries wifi first and if it fails, try from ethernet?

Thanks

Comment: some apps only work on one?  thats strange.

Comment: that is some services only available on ethernet domain, and firewall blocks some stuff on ethernet domain, where as works on wifi.